# Is it possible to check how much power is used by each USB port/device?

Tags: usb

I think in Windows, in Device Manager you can check how much current is supplied to each port - I don't think it is accurate though. I am thinking in Ubuntu, is it possible for me to know how much power is being consumed by each of my devices.

Comment: BTW, the max draw from each USB device is 500mA.

Comment: @user4901968 Yes, I know that. It is true for USB 2.0. But it is not what I am asking for.

Answer (score 2):

The same information that you can get in Windows Device Manger you can get by

```
usb-devices
```

It will show maximum power allocated to devices, but won't show real power consumption.

If you want to see the real figures, install and use `powertop` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no accurate way to see this but this will give you an idea...
(I think it displays the maximum amount of power the connected devices can/will use)

```
xxxxxx@lenox2:~$ usb-devices | grep 'Product=\|MxPwr'
    S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
    S:  Product=USB Gaming Mouse
    C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
    S:  Product=USB Keyboard
    C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
    S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
    S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
    S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
    S:  Product=USB Storage
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
```

If you really want to know exact:

https://superuser.com/questions/297959/how-do-you-check-how-much-power-a-usb-port-can-deliver/297960#297960

:)